# segfault during memcpy() of two char*

Tags: c, memcpy

I have the following:

```
//MTU = 1472  |  numBytes = 5000
/*char* data = 
#################################################
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
#################################################
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
#################################################
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
*/
char* payload = NULL;
size_t packetSize;
(numBytes > MTU) ? packetSize = MTU : packetSize = numBytes;

memcpy(payload, data, packetSize);
```

Whenever I try to do `memcpy` to copy the first `1472` bytes from `data` to `payload`, I get a segfault - any hints why?

Comment: You are copying `data` to a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 4):

You never initialize `payload`:

```
char* payload = NULL; // payload null
size_t packetSize;
(numBytes > MTU) ? packetSize = MTU : packetSize = numBytes;

memcpy(payload, data, packetSize); // copy data to null address ... segfault
```

Instead you'll need to `malloc` or `new`:

```
char* payload = new char[packetSize];
```

or

```
char* payload = (char*)malloc(packetSize);
```

... don't forget to `delete[]`/`free`

Comment: Op is asking in `c` and we can not use `new` in `c`

Comment: @someone : Originally he tagged `C++` also.

Answer (score 3):

`payload` is `NULL` so you cause undefined behaviour if you try to `memcpy` to it. Where do you think those bytes are going?

You have to allocate space to write it. For example:

```
payload = malloc(packetSize);
if ( !payload ) 
    { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* error handling */ }

memcpy(payload, data, packetSize);
// ...use payload...
free(payload);
```

Also you should check that `data` actually has as much data in it as `packetSize`. If you write `char const data[] = ".....";` then you can use `sizeof data - 1` to check this.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're trying to copy stuff to a null pointer. That's not the valid location of a buffer.